# Question of Arm performance related to register allocation

Tags: performance, assembly, cpu-architecture, arm64

I am currently measuring the performance of the code below on an embedded board with a cortex A77 cpu.

```
void kernel_func_x16(unsigned char* __restrict input_data, unsigned char* __restrict output_data)
{
    int stride_size=16;

    for(int i=0; i<100000000; i+=stride_size)
    {
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
    }
    return;
}
```

The size of each input / output buffer is approximately 96MB, and after running the kernel 1000 times, the performance value is measured as an average of removing the previous 200 times.
The measurement result of the code(**kernel_func_x16**) above is about 8.3 ms(with O3 option).

And running code(**kernel_func_x32**) below, the performance is measured around 11.1 ms.

```
void kernel_func_x32(unsigned char* __restrict input_data, unsigned char* __restrict output_data)
{
    int stride_size=32;

    for(int i=0; i<100000000; i+=stride_size)
    {
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
        *output_data++ = *input_data++;
    }
    return;
}
```

To find out why the above performance came out, generate each code as  assembly code. The code below is an assembly code created by adding the O3 options of **kernel_func_x16** and **kernel_func_x32** in order.

```
///// KERNEL_FUNC_X16 ///////
    .arch armv8.2-a+crc
    .file   "kernel.cpp"
    .text
    .align  2
    .p2align 4,,11
    .global _Z15kernel_func_x16PhS_
    .type   _Z15kernel_func_x16PhS_, %function
_Z15kernel_func_x16PhS_:
.LFB4340:
    .cfi_startproc
    mov x3, 57600
    mov x2, 0
    movk    x3, 0x5f5, lsl 16
    .p2align 3,,7
.L2:
    ldr q0, [x0, x2]
    str q0, [x1, x2]
    add x2, x2, 16
    cmp x2, x3
    bne .L2
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE4340:
    .size   _Z15kernel_func_x16PhS_, .-_Z15kernel_func_x16PhS_
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 11.1.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

```
///// KERNEL_FUNC_X32 ///////
    .arch armv8.2-a+crc
    .file   "kernel.cpp"
    .text
    .align  2
    .p2align 4,,11
    .global _Z15kernel_func_x32PhS_
    .type   _Z15kernel_func_x32PhS_, %function
_Z15kernel_func_x32PhS_:
.LFB4340:
    .cfi_startproc
    mov x3, 57600
    add x5, x0, 16
    add x4, x1, 16
    mov x2, 0
    movk    x3, 0x5f5, lsl 16
    .p2align 3,,7
.L2:
    ldr q1, [x0, x2]
    ldr q0, [x5, x2]
    str q1, [x1, x2]
    str q0, [x4, x2]
    add x2, x2, 32
    cmp x2, x3
    bne .L2
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE4340:
    .size   _Z15kernel_func_x32PhS_, .-_Z15kernel_func_x32PhS_
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 11.1.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

The key loop code of both assembly codes is located in the .L2 label.

It was difficult to find the reason of the performance degradation of **kernel_func_x32** at first, So i modify assembly code in various ways and analyze it.

First, I reorganized the instruction of **kernel_func_x32** to imitate the instruction sequence of **kernel_func_x16**.

```
    .arch armv8.2-a+crc
    .file   "kernel.cpp"
    .text
    .align  2
    .p2align 4,,11
    .global _Z15kernel_func_x32PhS_
    .type   _Z15kernel_func_x32PhS_, %function
_Z15kernel_func_x32PhS_:
.LFB4340:
    .cfi_startproc
    mov x3, 57600
    add x5, x0, 0
    add x4, x1, 0
    mov x2, 0
    movk    x3, 0x5f5, lsl 16
    .p2align 3,,7
.L2:
    ldr q1, [x0, x2]
    str q1, [x1, x2]
    add x2, x2, 16

    ldr q0, [x5, x2]
    str q0, [x4, x2]
    add x2, x2, 16
    cmp x2, x3
    bne .L2
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE4340:
    .size   _Z15kernel_func_x32PhS_, .-_Z15kernel_func_x32PhS_
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 11.1.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Since the above code has a load/store instruction structure similar to **kernel_func_x16** and execute fewer compare instrcution.
I guessed above code performance would be similar or faster then **kernel_func_x16**.

But when running that code, The performance is measured about 11ms.

While looking for the reason why the performance did not increase, I accidentally modify the code by replacing **x5**,**x4** registers with **x0**,**x1** as shown below.

```
    .arch armv8.2-a+crc
    .file   "kernel.cpp"
    .text
    .align  2
    .p2align 4,,11
    .global _Z15kernel_func_x32PhS_
    .type   _Z15kernel_func_x32PhS_, %function
_Z15kernel_func_x32PhS_:
.LFB4340:
    .cfi_startproc
    mov x3, 57600
    add x5, x0, 0
    add x4, x1, 0
    mov x2, 0
    movk    x3, 0x5f5, lsl 16
    .p2align 3,,7
.L2:
    ldr q1, [x0, x2]
    str q1, [x1, x2]
    add x2, x2, 16

    ldr q0, [x0, x2]
    str q0, [x1, x2]
    add x2, x2, 16
    cmp x2, x3
    bne .L2
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE4340:
    .size   _Z15kernel_func_x32PhS_, .-_Z15kernel_func_x32PhS_
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 11.1.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

For the code above, the performance is around 8.2 ms.
Although the operation is the same, the performance has been improved as the register names have been changed.
I searched several documents to find the reason, but couldn't find it.
I'd appreciate if someone could give me some advice.

Comment: taking measurements against an operating system is not consistent at best.  What was the alignment of the code and when you adjusted the alignment how did the performance change?

Comment: In your question all the kernels read to `w2` and write from `w2`, so there's no change in the code I can (easily) spot. I can only speculate that the loop length (more than 256 bytes) plays a role in the larger kernel.

Comment: If you are concerned about the performance, you should either have `__restrict` or `const uint8_t *input` so that you inform the compiler that `input` and `output` do not overlap. And if they do overlap, you should write the proper code to handle that, so all the variants will be (auto)vectorised -- and either follow the intended semantics of repeated overlapped segments, or memmove semantics.

Comment: @old_timer, I was trying various alignment combination from align(4) to align(16). But performance is still same.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen, The main performance bottle neck is L3 Label not L5. so code that you mention is same. main difference is L3 lable.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen, When i Add possible option such like you mention above comments, There are no meaningfull performance changes...

Comment: Strange thing is, When i move assembly code(KERNEL_FUNC_2 CODE) "add x5, x0, 16" and "add x4, x1, 16" from label .LFB4340 to .L3 at first line, the performance is closed to 8ms... I can't understand this behavior.

Comment: It's really hard to see the differences between the code blocks since you don't describe them in words, and to keep track of what speed each one ran at.  KERNEL_FUNC_1_Mod would be slower on an in-order ARM where the load-use latency would be a problem for storing right after a load.

Comment: @PeterCordes, My apologies, The code and explanations is hard to read. I will check my question more cleary and re-post my question again. I'm sorry to burden you.

Comment: Don't re-post it, just [edit] it.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I fix it more cleary Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your experiment indicates that on Cortex-A77 the encoding of the load instruction, in particular the base register, affects hardware prefetching. This is known to be the case for Falkor, a slightly older AArch64 CPU core designed by Qualcomm.

In case of Falkor, Linaro engineers contributed improvements related to prefetching to Glibc and GCC, and mentioned that not only the base and offset registers, but even the destination register affects the "tag" based on which the load address is routed to one of prefetch units:

https://inbox.sourceware.org/gcc-patches/20180724070741.25065-1-siddhesh@sourceware.org/

```
The falkor hardware prefetching system uses a combination of the
source, destination and offset to decide which prefetcher unit to
train with the load.  This is great when loads in a loop are
sequential but sub-optimal if there are unrelated loads in a loop that
tag to the same prefetcher unit.
```

https://inbox.sourceware.org/libc-alpha/1502134812-31816-1-git-send-email-siddhesh@sourceware.org/

```
+   FALKOR-SPECIFIC DESIGN:
+
+   The smallest copies (32 bytes or less) focus on optimal pipeline usage,
+   which is why the redundant copies of 0-3 bytes have been replaced with
+   conditionals, since the former would unnecessarily break across multiple
+   issue groups.  The medium copy group has been enlarged to 128 bytes since
+   bumping up the small copies up to 32 bytes allows us to do that without
+   cost and also allows us the reduce the size of the prep code before loop64.
+
+   All copies are done only via two registers r6 and r7.  This is to ensure
+   that all loads hit a single hardware prefetcher which can get correctly
+   trained to prefetch a single stream.
```

https://inbox.sourceware.org/libc-alpha/20180503175209.2943-1-siddhesh@sourceware.org/T/

```
The tail of the copy loops are unable to train the falkor hardware
prefetcher because they load from a different base compared to the hot
loop.
```

I do not have the same kind of evidence for Cortex-A77, but it seems plausible it might employ a similar trick.

Comment: Thanks, @amonakov, It really useful article.
I did a few more experiments, but the above seems to explain this situation.